# Easy method to install Python packages on Windows (7)?

Tags: python, windows, install.packages

I am upgrading my python to 3.4 from 3.2 but am hitting a brick wall with getting some of the packages that I work with (scipy, scipy-learn, not bothered to try further yet).

As previously, I have gone round in circles trying to get pip and easy_install to work. As before, I've resorted to the heroic Christoph Gohlke's binaries. However, now the binaries are Wheel files.

Unfortunately, using pip install mydownloadedwheelfile.whl also throws errors such as "not a valid wheel filename" or "not a valid wheel resource". Stack exchange provides answers to all the errors I encounter, but often I encounter further errors trying to resolve the problems. After 1.5 hours I have still only managed to install numpy (which miraculously worked first time with pip).

My question therefore is, how do people using windows install python packages painlessly?

Any tips would be very gratefully received. Please don't suggest I install linux. Many thanks in advance,
Izzy

Comment: I just installed numpy and scipy wheels from Gohlke's site (`cp34-none-win_amd64` architecture) in a virtual environment using the following command: `pip install --pre --no-index --find-links=/path/to/wheels numpy scipy`. The virtual environment named "test" was created with the following command: `py -3.4 -m venv --symlinks test`, and then activated via `test\Scripts\activate.bat`. With a local wheel cache and requirements files you can easily load various work environments without having to re-download packages from PyPI.

Comment: Thank you eryksun, I have tried what you suggest although I must confess that I don't fully understand the part abou the virtual environment. Unfortunately I still get errors. I tried setting the --find-links to the local directory with the wheel file (from Gohlke's page), directly to Christoph Gohlke's site or removing this option altogether but got the error 'could not find a version that satisfies the requirement scipy'.

Comment: Check `"%userprofile%\pip\pip.log"` for a more detailed reason for the failure. Did you use the `--pre` option? Some of Gohlke's wheels are a pre-release version that pip won't install otherwise. Also, are you downloading the right architecture? `win32` is for 32-bit Python while `win_amd64` is for 64-bit Python; often 32-bit Python is installed even on 64-bit Windows.

Comment: See [Creating Virtual Environments](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/installing.html#creating-virtual-environments). `pyvenv` is a script for using the standard library's `venv` module. However, that script isn't necessarily on the `PATH` in Windows, so I run the module directly using `py -3.4 -m venv <OPTIONS> <DIR>`.

Answer (score 0):

eryksun, thank you for all your input, I really appreciate the time you've put in and hopefully it will be helpful to others as well.

The answer I found to my question was simply to install WinPython http://winpython.sourceforge.net/. Its obvious, but I was unaware of the package. It contains all the packages I need (except cPickle, apparently).